# 2D std::vector array to glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl, stdvector

I'm trying to use a 2D vector array of GLfloats to draw a grid. I cant seem to get the right code for glBufferData with a 2d vector instead of the examples I see online which are for 1D.

UPDATED - I have to multply glBufferData by 2 or else only half the grid gets drawn....

```
struct point
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
};

float gridMinus = flatGrid_lines / 2.0f;
//point Vertices[20][20];

GLfloat HEIGHT = 20.0f;
GLfloat WIDTH = 20.0f;

vector<point> VerticesD(flatGrid_lines * flatGrid_lines);

//VERTICAL LINES
for (int i = 0; i < flatGrid_lines; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < flatGrid_lines; j++)
    {
        VerticesD[i + j * flatGrid_lines].x = (j - gridMinus) / gridMinus;
        VerticesD[i + j * flatGrid_lines].y = (i - gridMinus) / gridMinus;
    }
}

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_grid1);
glBindVertexArray(vao_grid1);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_grid1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_grid1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VerticesD.size() * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), &VerticesD[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: A `vector<vector<...>>` does not necessarily store its data in a continuous memory block. Is there a reason why you don't use a simple array? If you want to use a vector, you should linearize the data (e.g. map index `(i,j)` to `i + j * width`).

Comment: So if I did a 1d array then I would have to multiply the glBufferData by 2, right? Ex: glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VerticesD.size() * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), &VerticesD[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Comment: Why do you want to multiply it by 2? You need the buffer's byte size. This is *number of elements * size of one element*.

Comment: If I dont multiply by 2 only half the grid lines get drawn. Original question updated.

Comment: That's because `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)` is exactly the element size of `sizeof(point)`. You can use it, however, it is more readable to use `sizeof(point)`.